# MediaElement is not working for Xamarin Android -10

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mediaelement

Trying with MediaElement in Xamarin.

It is not working in android 10 when taking video from 'raw' folder.
We are not facing this issue in Android 9.
We are not facing this issue if we are giving a URL as a source.

demo project is added in the following link--> https://github.com/devcrux/Xamarin.Forms-Shapes

Steps followed.
1.Added ' Device.SetFlags(new[] { "Shapes_Experimental", "MediaElement_Experimental" });' in App class.
2.Added mp4 file in row folder
3.Build action is given as 'Android Resource'
4.MediaElement is added like

```
 <MediaElement
            x:Name="mediaElementBar"
            Source="https://qdserversas1.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:571/video/hospital.mp4"
            ShowsPlaybackControls="False" 
                      IsLooping="True" Aspect="AspectFill" AutoPlay="True"
            SeekCompleted="mediaElementBar_SeekCompleted"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

.
Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Could you please manage to upgrade the Nuget packages to the latest version and try again?